# How to verify the derived type of a parameter passed to a mocked function

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I have a base class and two derived classes, like this:

```
class Base { ... };
class DerivedA : public Base { ... };
class DerivedB : public Base { ... };
```

I also have an interface class which I'm mocking (with Google Mock), like this:

```
class MockSomeInterface : public SomeInterface
{
  public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(someMethod, void(Base* basePtr));
};
```

I can expect calls to the mocked method like this, not verifying the parameter in the call at all:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mockSomeInterfaceObj, someMethod(_))
  Times(2);
```

What i would like to do is verify the type of the parameter given to `someMethod`, to check that it is in fact called with a `DerivedA*` once and a `DerivedB*` once, instead of just twice with any parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write matcher functions for this. Your expectations will then look like this

```
{
  InSequence s;
  EXPECT_CALL(mockSomeInterfaceObj, someMethod(IsDerivedA()))
    Times(1);
  EXPECT_CALL(mockSomeInterfaceObj, someMethod(IsDerivedB()))
    Times(1);
}
```

if you have defined the following matcher functions:

```
MATCHER(IsDerivedA, "")
{
  if (arg == NULL)
  {
    return false;
  }
  DerivedA* derived = dynamic_cast<DerivedA*>(arg);
  if (derived == NULL)
  {
    *result_listener << "is NOT a DerivedA*";
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

MATCHER(IsDerivedB, "")
{
  if (arg == NULL)
  {
    return false;
  }
  DerivedB* derived = dynamic_cast<DerivedB*>(arg);
  if (derived == NULL)
  {
    *result_listener << "is NOT a DerivedB*";
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Notice though that if it's not a pointer parameter but a reference, `dynamic_cast` will throw an `std::bad_cast` instead of returning `NULL`, in the case of types not matching (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).

Answer (score 1):

gMock provides a pointer matcher which can be used to match base class pointer to derived class object arguments. (https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md#pointer-matchers)

```
using ::testing::NotNull;
using ::testing::WhenDynamicCastTo;

EXPECT_CALL(mockSomeInterfaceObj, someMethod(WhenDynamicCastTo<DerivedA*>(NotNull()))).Times(1);
EXPECT_CALL(mockSomeInterfaceObj, someMethod(WhenDynamicCastTo<DerivedB*>(NotNull()))).Times(1);
```